# How to check data for previous 3 month and next 3 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am working with telecom data. So basically I have mobile numbers and I need to have a flag (Yes/ No) that has following conditions.

Flag 'Yes' if,

1. Invoice month must be at-least for 3 months
2. Total_Minutes_Used=0
3. Total_Data_Usage_MB=0
4. Case if Total_Minutes_Used=0 OR Total_Data_Usage_MB=0 for next 3 months (to check for +- 3 months) else 'No'

Sample data

```
Mobile Number  Invoice_Month Total_Minutes_Used Total_Data_Usage_MB
------------- -------------- ------------------ -------------------
9112222210          01-2019     0                 0
9112222210          02-2019     0                 0
9112222210          03-2019     0                 45
9112222210          04-2019     0                 0
9112222211          01-2019     0                 0
9112222211          02-2019     0                 0
9112222211          03-2019     0                 0
9112222211          04-2019     0                 0
9112222212          01-2019     0                 0
9112222212          02-2019     0                 0
9112222212          03-2019     0                 0
9112222212          04-2019     0                 50
```

Expected Output

```
Mobile Number  Invoice_Month Total_Minutes_Used Total_Data_Usage_MB       Flag
------------- -------------- ------------------ -------------------       ----
9112222210          01-2019     0                 0      N
9112222210          02-2019     0                 0      N
9112222210          03-2019     0                 45     N
9112222210          04-2019     0                 0      N
9112222211          01-2019     0                 0      N
9112222211          02-2019     0                 0      N
9112222211          03-2019     0                 0      Y
9112222211          04-2019     0                 0      Y
9112222212          01-2019     0                 0      N
9112222212          02-2019     0                 0      N
9112222212          03-2019     0                 0      N
9112222212          04-2019     0                 50     N
```

I tried it with LEAD and LAG but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Can you please share the query you have tried, even if it throwing the error is also fine.

Comment: Are you looking at the next three months, or previous three *and* next three? And what does *Invoice month must be at-least for 3 months* mean?

Comment: @Shawn previous three and next three. at-least for 3 months mean the mobile number must have at-least 3 invoices.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
select *, 
case when Invoice_Month <= DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()) AND
          Total_Minutes_Used=0 AND
          Total_Data_Usage_MB=0 AND
          Total_Minutes_Used=0 OR Total_Data_Usage_MB=0 THEN "YES"
          ELSE "NO"
          END AS FLAG 
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Just glancing at the source data, Invoice_Month is not in the datetime format and would need transformation to be used with DATEADD.  Which is probably one of the hurdles OP is facing.